# Which font should I use in PHP image to get text border effect

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to make a code which would take input for an image and insert the text.
The output which I am expecting is one like this image-
[image]

You can see the it appears like it is the text shadow/border. The text is `Khadim Hussain`(in red), and `(Khadim Hussain Rasooli)`(in green).

I am using the image GD library of PHP to insert the text. The code is-

```
$font = 'font/HelveticaNeueLTCom-XBlkCn.ttf';
$bbox = imagettfbbox ( 10, 0, $font, $text );
$glow_color = imagecolorallocate($im,0xFF,0xFF,0x00);
$shadow_color = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
$x = 200;
$y = 268;
imagettftextblur($im, 24,0, $x, $y,$shadow_color,$font,$text,0,-1);
```

For which I have this output-
[image]

You can see I could not get the desired effect, which is there in the previous snap.
I want the code in a way that the text should fit exactly in red section of the previous snap.

PS- The first snap is generated from photoshop and I want the same to achieve threw PHP.

Update: The pic is a cover of the facebook profile such that the text there acts as background of the Profile Name of the user. Here is a snap of the same snap-
[image]

Comment: Use the same font/size, only with a thicker, more prominent glow.

Comment: @Fred I am also trying to have the same font, but this is what I got best. Thing is, this is a cover for the facebook profile where this pic is cover pic with the text at the position so that it acts as the background of the profile name. I am updating my question for the sake of complete info

Comment: Ah I see. Hm, it's going to be hard to get it "right on the nose", if you don't know what the exact font that was used, the size (points, mm etc.) and kerning (aka spacing).

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting is impossible.  The text will be rendered slightly differently depending on which OS & browser the user is ending whereas the background image with the glow will have to be set once universally.  I am happy to see you using my imagettftextblur() function though.